# How to share state between IDbCommandTreeInterceptors and IDbCommandInterceptors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Both `DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext` and `DbCommandInterceptionContext` contain a `UserState` property, but it's not transferred from one to the other. I.E. in this case:

```
public class DummyDbCommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor 
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
         interceptionContext.UserState = "test";
    }
}

public class DummyDbCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, 
         DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
         if (interceptionContext.UserState != "test")
         {
              throw new Exception("wtf");
         }
    }
}
```

The exception will be thrown. Is there any way to share the state between the two?

Comment: Each interception pipeline uses its own context. I think it wouldn't be desirable to have any interaction between them because they serve different purposes. Also, `UserState` is not a property of the base `DbInterceptionContext` class, they are separate properties in both subtypes. *And* `UserState` is obsolete. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve so we can help find an alternative.

Comment: You're right, it's not in the base class and there is no connection between the two. It seemed weird at first, but on the second thought, the query plans can be cached and the DbCommandTreeInterceptors may not be fired on subsequent queries, so not sharing the UserState makes sense. It would be nice to have access to the DbExpressionTree from the DbCommandInterceptors, but it's not supported according to a comment of this blog post: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/14/ef6-sql-logging-part-3-interception-building-blocks/